# ActiveRecord custom after callback current_scope is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model (let's call it Blog). It looks like:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author

  def self.foo_all
    all.each(&:bar)
  end

  def bar
    author.baz
  end
end
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that when `author.blogs.foo_all` method is called, it seems that the `Blog` class has a `current_scope`! This means that when inside the `author.baz` method, any query on `Blog` has the `author` as a scope on the query (`WHERE authors.id == 123`)!

Using an example where

- blog.id == 123
- author.id == 456

this is what happens:

```
Class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs

  def baz
    id # 456
    blogs.count # "SELECT count(*) FROM blogs WHERE blogs.author_id == 456"
    Blog.count # "SELECT count(*) FROM blogs WHERE blogs.author_id == 456"
    Blog.current_scope # "[Blog id: 123, author_id: 456]"
  end
end
```

Yes, I can work around this why explicitly removing that scope, but it's SO unexpected! In what world does `Blog.count` not perform an unscoped query?!

Note: I do not use a `default_scope` anywhere.

Rails: 6.1.3.2

Copy of code with rspec test that replicates the problem https://github.com/hrdwdmrbl/StockOverflow69020511

Comment: Its somewhat explained by the [`scope` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L100) which power halfs of ActiveRecord. Why on earth some sort of thread local class level state is needed in the first place can probally only be explained by DHH.

Comment: Which version of rails are you on?

Comment: I think `Blog` should `belongs_to :author` not `has_one :author` no?

Comment: I have exactly duplicated the code you have shown (except for changing `has_one :author` to `belongs_to :author` and I do not see the behaviour that you are reporting. Rails 6.1.4.1. Suggest you spin up a new Rails app with just the `Author` and `Blog` models and see if the anomaly you are reporting still exists in a virgin app.

Comment: @JeremyRamos 6.1.3.2

Comment: @LesNightingill You are right, changed `has_one :author` to `belongs_to :author`.

Comment: @LesNightingill I will try that.

Comment: given the code you have shown, what exact steps do you do to reproduce the problem? I just did `Author.first.baz` and saw the expected queries (not the ones that you have seen). I also tried `Blog.first.bar` and saw the expected queries.

Comment: I also tried `Blog.first.update_foo`. It works as expected. I suspect there is something in your actual app other than what you have shown, that is causing the problem.

Comment: Do `Blog` and `Author` both inherit from `ApplicationRecord`?

Comment: @LesNightingill Yes, calling `update_foo` is the right move. That is the situation. I use a test to reproduce the error. Yes, they inherit from AR. I updated my question with that. I will try making a simple app to replicate and I'll share a github link.

Comment: @LesNightingill I did the same, created a Rails app with just those models and at first I couldn't replicate the problem. Then I realized the key! It is a side-effect of ActiveRecord::Relation methods. To trigger it, you have to have:

```
class Blog
  def self.foo_all
    all.each(&:update_foo)
  end
end
```

and then run `author.blogs.foo_all`

Comment: @LesNightingill I corrected my question. And minimal implementation https://github.com/hrdwdmrbl/StockOverflow69020511

Comment: @LesNightingill Honestly now that I understand the true requirements to replicate, it makes much more sense! By having that method chain `author.blogs`, author is set as a current_scope of Blog. Still totally unexpected and I would definitely call it a bug, but I see how it's a tricky situation!

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl thanks for following up. Congratulations on isolating the cause. You may wish to report it as a bug, to see if the Rails gods agree.